# How to use python multiprocessing to get a global sum after traversing through http requests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to write an algorithm that traverses the entire collection of nodes and returns the sum of their rewards. Each reward should only be counted a single time. The input to the algorithm will be a URL for a node to begin with, such as http://fake.url/a.

Each get request of the URL will return a JSON like this:

```
{
      "children":[
        "http://fake.url/b",
        "http://fake.url/c"
      ],
      "reward":1
    }
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
import multiprocessing
import requests
import json

my_q = multiprocessing.Queue()
my_list  =['http://fake.url/']
reward_sum = 0

def enqueue(q):
    for data in my_list:
        q.put(data)

def get_it(q):
    while not q.empty():
        item = q.get()
        print(item)
        response = requests.get(item)
        kids = json.loads(response.content)
        print(f'URL: {item} --> {kids["reward"]}')
        for kid in kids['children']:
            print(kid)
            q.put(kid)

p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=enqueue, args=(my_q,))
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=get_it, args=(my_q,))
p1.start()
p2.start()

p1.join()
p2.join()
```

What works above:

1. I am using multiprocessing.
2. I am accessing the children and rewards correctly.
3. I am getting output like this:

```
    http://fake.url/a
    URL: http://fake.url/a --> 1
    {'children': ['http://fake.url/b', 'http://fake.url/c'], 'reward': 1}
    http://fake.url/b
    http://fake.url/c
    http://fake.url/b
    URL: http://fake.url/b --> 2
    {'children': ['http://fake.url/d', 'http://fake.url/e'], 'reward': 2}
    http://fake.url/d
    http://fake.url/e
    http://fake.url/c
    URL: http://fake.url/c --> 3
    {'children': ['http://fake.url/f', 'http://fake.url/g'], 'reward': 3}
    http://fake.url/f
    http://fake.url/g
    http://fake.url/d
    URL: http://fake.url/d --> 4
    {'reward': 4}
    http://fake.url/e
    URL: http://fake.url/e --> 5
    {'reward': 5}
    http://fake.url/f
    URL: http://fake.url/f --> 6
    {'children': ['http://fake.url/h'], 'reward': 6}
    http://fake.url/h
    http://fake.url/g
```

What are the problems I need help with:

1. How to keep track of the total reward sum in a global variable?
2. How to keep track of a global "seen" set, so I don't add duplicates to the total reward sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def get_it(q):
    rewards_total = 0
    seen = set()
    while not q.empty():
        item = q.get()
        print(item)
        if item in seen:
            continue
        seen.add(item)
        response = requests.get(item)
        kids = json.loads(response.content)
        rewards_total += kids["reward"]
        print(f'URL: {item} --> {kids["reward"]}')
        for kid in kids['children']:
            print(kid)
            q.put(kid)
    return rewards_total
```

Comment: Why is it when I add a print statement right before the return like this: print(f'rewards total: {rewards_total}') the progress doesn't loop through the children like before?

Comment: Strange; shouldn't happen.